# Including several impedance in VRP solve with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, vehicle-routing-problem

Let's say the travel time as impedance is various in two directions of a two-way link "FT" and "TF", and also it varies by time-of-day. How can I introduce multiple impedance for solving a dynamic vehicle routing problem in Arcpy.

As I see, I can give a list separated by semicolon as accumulators, but they are not entered in analysis, and just are calculated as the properties of solved route.

Comment: Two lines, one for the FT and another for the TF with the different impedance for each?

Comment: No, I have one line with a field "oneway = 0" which indicates that t is two-way link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution to your question is explained in [evaluators help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-evaluators-used-by-a-network.htm) where you can set different frictions to the directions in a field (see the first evaluator example in the link).

In another [exercise](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-11-solving-a-network-analysis-using-traffic-data.htm), it is advised to create different network datasets (by simply copying, pasting and reconfiguring) for the time span that you are targeting. Alternatively, you can introduce approximate impedances in a functional fashion by using evaluators again.